# PrimeNg Global Filter through Module not found error

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to implement [PrimeNg Global filter](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v7.2.6-lts/#/table/filter) and followed the documentation they provided.

But I am getting below error. I am not sure how to add this Module separately.

They have [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) link, but there I don't see any error on that specific module.

Also I am using Angular Version 7 and PrimeNg version 7.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why you import FilterUtils?
as you can see in primeNg document(v7) you have to import TableModule.

```
npm install @angular/cdk --save
import {TableModule} from 'primeng/table';
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by above answer, i have removed the FilterUtils component but then i got different error which is self-explanatory.

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Global filtering requires dynamic columns or globalFilterFields to be defined.
```

So i have added "globalFilterFields" fix like below and then everything is fine.

```
<p-table #dt [resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="fit" [value]="tbldata" [(first)]="first" [paginator]="tbldata.length>10" [rows]="10" styleClass="dataTable" [globalFilterFields]="['firstName', 'lastName', 'age', 'company']">
```